# How to add a value to a *vector?

Tags: c++

In my header file I have this vector defined as a pointer.

```
private:
    vector<filteredPoint_t> *filteredValues;
```

In my cpp file I want to add an instance of (struct) `filterPoint_t` to this vector. It compiles.

```
filteredPoint_t fp;
fp.filteredValue = 3.4;
fp.globalIndex = 3;
filteredValues->push_back(fp);
```

However, when I run it, it stops immediately after the invocation of `filteredValues->push_back(fp)`. Not even `prinf` console outputs are shown. No error message though on the console.

What am I missing here?

Some background information: I need to pass `filteredValues` to multiple threads. So that every thread can write back into this variable. Therefore I thought I would use a pointer variable to do so.

Comment: Are you initializing that pointer to something?

Comment: Do you allocate the vector? Also, you say you want to use it from multiple threads, do you have appropriate locking in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory first ( may be constructor ) or point it to valid `vector<filteredPoint_t>` address:

```
 filteredValues = new vector<filteredPoint_t>() ;
```

Then you can use `push_back` on to it.

Also, make sure you de-allocate the memory allocated using `new` in the destructor

```
delete [] filteredValues ;
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. As a newbie in C++ I forgot about the allocation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pointer, that means it must point to something valid in order to be used:

```
vector<filteredPoint_t> *filteredValues;
```

if you don't, you're going to dereference an uninitialized pointer and invoke undefined behavior.

Initializing means either:

- Having it point to something valid (i.e. an already existing vector)

  ```
  filteredValues = &existingVectorOfTheSameType;
  ```
- Creating a new heap vector yourself, e.g.

  ```
  filteredValues = new vector<filteredPoint_t>();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. As a newbie in C++ I forgot about the allocation.